# Tail bound for hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, hypergeometric-function, distribution-tails

I am looking for a reference (book) for the tail bound for the Hypergeometric distribution.

I know there is a nice paper by Skala (2009) but its unpublished. I am looking for a book which would be a nice reference.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

(1) Cite the Chvatal or Hoeffding papers, which were published.

(2) Johnson et. al, "Univariate Discrete Distributions," 3e. Wiley-Interscience, 2005. Section 6.5 (p.268) contains some bounds for the Hypergeometric, though I don't know whether they're the same as the ones in Skala (2009).